# Setting text of TextView in android in a loop

Tags: android, loops, while-loop, textview, settext

i'm trying to set text of text view in a while loop as

```
 t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
    while(true)  
    {  
     t.setText(hr+":"+":"min+":"+sec);  
      try{  
          Thread.sleep(1000);  
         }  
      catch(Exception e){}  
    }
```

But while running the app text is not changing. when i removed the while loop then it was setting
text correctly.
why was so? Plz Help!!!!!!!!!**strong text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never change the values of hr, min and sec. Also you are calling  `Thread.sleep(1000);`  on the UI Thread, which is responsable to draw the text in your text view. Of course, it will be unable to do that while it is sleeping.

Comment: i'm calling a method logic() as a first line in while loop in which i'm changing the values of hr,min,sec accordingly. but nevertheless it is not changing. when i remove only while loop and remaining body same then it works fine.  Why is it so?